# What causes python IDE to report "Cannot find reference '[' in 'function'"

Tags: python-3.x, ide

When editing the following:

line_ar = fflistline.split
if line_ar[0] == "file":

My python IDE reported

> Cannot find reference '[' in 'function in the second line

The problem is that fflistline.split is assigning the function fflistline.split to line_ar and not calling the function fflistline.split() and assigning that list to line_ar.

I took turns staring at that and searching for that error message for 10 minutes  before I took a break and I still had to work on something else for a while before the missing empty () flashed in to my brain.  Maybe IDE's should come with a setting that warns about this.  If I had typed it in directly it would have autocompleted the () so I guess it must have been a cut and paste or an edit error somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fflistline.split without the () resolves to the  function fflistline.split  and not to the array that results form calling the function fflistline.split().